# $_POST echoing 0 when containing strings

Tags: php, forms, post

I made a basic HTML form working with post (it's a login form). The form itself works great, but when I try to work with the information contained in $_POST it goes wrong.

```
<?php
        // case : nothing submitted
        if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        ?>
            <div class="login">
                <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
                    <p>Login</p>
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
                    <button name="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php
        // case : input form submitted
        } else {
            check_credentials();            
        }
?>
```

The problem is, it works fine when I do this ( above `check_credentials()` : 

`echo $_POST['username'];
echo $_POST['password'];`

But when I do this : 
`echo $_POST['username'] + " " + $_POST['password'];`

It echoes 0. As `check_credentials()` is a function that connects to my DB, the request isn't executed. Does someone have any idea of the possible cause ?

Greetz !

Comment: Because you're using Java-type concatenation, not PHP. PHP thinks you're doing math (adding things together). It should be `echo $_POST['username'] ." ". $_POST['password'];` instead, which is the way to concat strings in PHP.

Comment: Concatenate strings using the .(dot) Operator.

Comment: Thanks guys ! I completely forgot PHP concatenation was with dot operator !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use dots when concatenating in PHP. You probably "took" pluses from JS.

It should look like in this example:

```
    <?php
    $a = "Hello ";
    $b = $a . "World!"; // now $b contains "Hello World!"
    $a = "Hello ";
    $a .= "World!";     // now $a contains "Hello World!"
    ?>
```

And your example, if the variables are good:

```
  echo $_POST['username']." ".$_POST['password'];
```